# Stimulate real time data

Tags: time

I had historical data collected by sensors and would like to create a web interface project where users could observe the life-stream analytics displayed on it. May I know which specific platform (ex: Azure) could help in utilizing my existing data and stream records of data at a time interval to create the stimulation of a real scenario?

Comment: If you use R, [shiny](https://shiny.rstudio.com/) is a great option.

Comment: thanks. could R be able to stimulate real-time data transfer as the web interface updates itself?

Comment: The code to transmit the data to the frontend is up to the programmer. For example it could be a matter of updating a database and the interface reading from it. What Shiny does is dynamically draw some plots based on some user inputs, it's really the interface.